# Why is grabCurrentURL() not returning the current URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In `popup.js` in my Google Chrome extension, I have:

```
function sendWebResponse(hash) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/tasks/4123434/from_chrome");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token token=463c121664d98a6dafd1086e8d0ecca0');
  xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(hash));  
}

function grabCurrentUrl(url) {
  chrome.tabs.query(
    {'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, 
      function (tabs) {
        var url = tabs[0].url;
        return url;
      }
)};
```

The following works:

```
function submitTrue(id) {
  sendWebResponse({"survey": id,"result": "true");
}
```

But the following does not:

```
function submitTrue(id) {
  var url = grabCurrentUrl();
  sendWebResponse({"survey": id,"result": "true", "url": url});
}
```

In this case, `url` is `null`. There definitely is an active tab when I do this.

Why is `grabCurrentURL()` not grabbing the active tab's current URL?

Comment: 'Why is grabCurrentURL() not grabbing the active tab's current URL?'
Depends on when you're asking it to retrieve the tabs, as far as i know tabs.query is asynchron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what they are all saying about it being async.  You can change getCurrentUrl to be this:

```
function getCurrentUrl(callback) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        if (tabs.length > 0) { 
           callback(tabs[0].url);    
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

Then you change your submitTrue to be:

```
function submitTrue(id) {
  getCurrentUrl(function(url) {
      sendWebResponse({"survey": id,"result": "true", "url": url});
  });
}
```

Comment: strangely sometimes working and sometimes not -- have tried `currentWindow` instead of `lastFocusedWindow` and still sometimes working and sometimes not -- very odd -- i'm thinking that maybe (a) the pop-up becomes the last focused tab, or (b) the active tab does not have a URL at certain times, such as when the page is still loading

Comment: an earlier method is 100% successful in identifying the correct tab so I'm going to try storing the tab.id in a global variable and using it to retrieve the correct tab later

Comment: This worked, where currentTabID is a global variable:

function getCurrentUrl(callback) {
  chrome.tabs.get(currentTabID, function(retrieveTab) {
    callback(retrieveTab.url);
  })
  return null;
}